Error Compiling QCAD with Qt 5.15.2 and MinGW: limits: No such file or directory
Description:
I am trying to compile QCAD using Qt 5.15.2 and MinGW on Windows. I have successfully run the qmake command, but when I try to build the project using mingw32-make, I encounter an error related to the <limits> header file.
Steps to Reproduce:

Open Command Prompt.

Navigate to the QCAD source directory: D:\cad\qcad.

Run the qmake command:
D:\cad\qcad>D:/Qt/5.15.2/mingw81_64/bin/qmake.exe -r CONFIG+=ractivated

D:\cad\qcad>D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j32


Error Message:
In file included from dxflib.rc:5:
src/dl_dxf.h:30:10: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
 #include <limits>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
windres: preprocessing failed.
mingw32-make[4]: *** [Makefile.Release:82: D:/cad/qcad/release/dxflib_res.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'D:/cad/qcad/src/3rdparty/dxflib'
mingw32-make[3]: *** [Makefile:45: release] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'D:/cad/qcad/src/3rdparty/dxflib'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile:657: sub-dxflib-release_ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/cad/qcad/src/3rdparty'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:1118: sub-3rdparty-release_ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/cad/qcad/src'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:457: sub-src-release_ordered] Error 2

Environment:
Operating System: Windows 10/11
Qt Version: 5.15.2
MinGW Version: 8.1.0
QCAD Version: 3.31.2.0
What I Have Tried:

Ensured that the MinGW bin directory (D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin) is added to the system PATH.
Verified that the limits header file exists in the MinGW include directory (D:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/include/c++/8.1.0).
Cleaned the project and rebuilt it using mingw32-make clean followed by mingw32-make.
I have previously compiled QCAD using Qt 5.15.2 and MinGW on Ubuntu, and it was successful.

Additional Information:

The limits header file is part of the C++ standard library and should be available in the MinGW installation.
The error occurs during the preprocessing of the resource file dxflib.rc.

Question:
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
